# Arcpy: replaceDataSource, cad_workspace

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am having trouble replacing the data source on CAD files using arcpy.

Everything I have tried runs into this error:

```
Runtime error type 'exceptions.ValueError' : Layer: Unexpected error
```

Here is a list of arguments I have tried:

```
layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/CAD_File_1.dxf', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'Polyline')

layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/CAD_File_1', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'Polyline')

layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'CAD_File_1/Polyline')

layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'CAD_File_1.dxf/Polyline')

layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'CAD_File_1.dxf.Polyline')

layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'CAD_File_1.Polyline')
```

It appears to take more time to think about going wrong when I put the 'CAD_File_1*' part in the 'Dataset_Name' section, that is to the right of 'CAD_WORKSPACE'.  But it still fails.

I have noticed that it treats the CAD file as a Feature Dataset and the particular feature type, in this case Polyline, as the Feature Class which may be the issue.

I have also tried this when pointing at a 'Polyline' layer:

```
layer.replaceDataSource('C:/CAD_DIR/', 'CAD_WORKSPACE', 'CAD_File_1.dxf)
```

It doesn't produce the same error or in fact any error but the data does not update.

Comment: You used double quotation marks at the beginning of the first parameter (") but ended with single quotation marks (').  Sometimes it doesn't make a difference, but since ValueError is parameter-related you want to make sure those string parameters are being passed properly.

Comment: Good point, but that is just my mistake when writing the example here. For the most part I am trying to make changes in batch so syntax like that is assigned automatically when I pull the string from a CSV. I will edit to remove that mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If this is still an issue there is some discussion here that may or may not help: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/46682-replaceDataSource-OR-findAndReplaceWorkspacePath-for-CAD-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logged as bug by ESRI:

Bug #NIM078454

Answer (score 1):

Bug indeed, but since I am stuck on 10.0 for another year the 10.1 fix didn't help me yet. Since this is still one of the first results on my Google search for the topic, I thought I'd come back and add my answer.

The workaround [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8573-ReplaceDataSource-not-working-in-script) solved the issue for me. To summarize, save a reference to the layer, remove the later from the map document, update the data source, and re-add it.

I was unable to replace CAD sources properly, but ended up using the 'NONE' keyword for the workspace_type parameter and it looped through the sources in the new folder until it found one with the name specified.

Comment: Thanks for the update brichins, I haven't looked at that code for about 18 months now.  When I get a chance I will check it out.